# How do I generate a random 10 digit number in ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

Additionally, how can I format it as a string padded with zeros?

Answer (score 97):

To generate the number call rand with the result of the expression "10 to the power of 10"

```
rand(10 ** 10)
```

To pad the number with zeros you can use the string format operator

```
'%010d' % rand(10 ** 10)
```

or the `rjust` method of string

```
rand(10 ** 10).to_s.rjust(10,'0')
```

Comment: I just realized that with this method you can still end up with `0000000000`. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: not correct because sometimes it returns 1 or 2 less digit count number. i.e. 252402199, 12348208 for above. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 66):

I would like to contribute probably a simplest solution I know, which is a quite a good trick.

```
rand.to_s[2..11] 
 => "5950281724"
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it gives you a string, so if you really need a number you then have to cast it (again) - which is a bit messy.

Comment: Worth noting it'll only give you up to 16 digits though.

Comment: This is not recommended. It will not always be the expected length, as `rand` may may return a float value as low as `0.0`, and the resulting string would be `"0"`. If you'd like to confirm, try this out in `irb` by running `(0.0).to_s[2..11]`.

Answer (score 40):

This is a fast way to generate a 10-sized string of digits:

```
10.times.map{rand(10)}.join # => "3401487670"
```

Comment: The first number might be a zero though which results in a nine digit number though.

Comment: @GeorgeYacoub I think OP wanted a zero padded string as end result.

Comment: This does indeed satisfy all the demands noted by the OP - even when the first digit is a number.

Comment: More performant way to achieve the same thing: `Array.new(10) { rand(10) }`

Answer (score 18):

The most straightforward answer would probably be

`rand(1e9...1e10).to_i`

The `to_i` part is needed because `1e9` and `1e10` are actually floats:

```
irb(main)> 1e9.class
=> Float
```

Comment: This is even faster than both of the Benchmark examples put forth by @NhatTan.

`puts Benchmark.measure{(1..1000000).map{rand(1e9...1e10).to_i}}`

I actually need a string as my end result, but even adding `.to_s` at the end still yields a faster result.

`puts Benchmark.measure{(1..1000000).map{rand(1e9...1e10).to_i.to_s}}`

Comment: I just tried this, but could never observe it starting with a 0, even though it has fixed length.
`10000.times.map{rand(1e9...1e10).to_i.to_s}.select!{|x| x.start_with?("0")}` yields []

Comment: @OskarHolmkratz this code generates a number between 1000000000 and 9999999999.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. I wasn't even aware of the _three_ dot variant. I've always used two dots. That's excellent.

Comment: sucessfully generated two million unique numbers. I used securerandom because rand() stoped being unique at 500k. SecureRandom.random_number(1e9...1e10).to_s[0..15].tr('.', '').to_i

Answer (score 12):

### DON'T USE `rand.to_s[2..11].to_i`

Why? Because here's what you can get:

```
rand.to_s[2..9] #=> "04890612"
```

and then:

```
"04890612".to_i #=> 4890612
```

Note that:

```
4890612.to_s.length #=> 7
```

Which is not what you've expected!

To check that error in your own code, instead of `.to_i` you may wrap it like this:

```
Integer(rand.to_s[2..9])
```

and very soon it will turn out that:

```
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "02939053"
```

So it's always better to stick to `.center`, but keep in mind that:

```
rand(9)
```

sometimes may give you `0`.

To prevent that:

```
rand(1..9)
```

which will always return something withing `1..9` range.

I'm glad that I had good tests and I hope you will avoid breaking your system.

Answer (score 12):

### Random number generation

Use [Kernel#rand](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) method:

```
rand(1_000_000_000..9_999_999_999) # => random 10-digits number
```

### Random string generation

Use `times` + `map` + `join` combination:

```
10.times.map { rand(0..9) }.join # => random 10-digit string (may start with 0!)
```

### Number to string conversion with padding

Use [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) method:

```
"%010d" % 123348 # => "0000123348"
```

### Password generation

Use [KeePass password generator](https://github.com/johnbintz/keepass-password-generator) library, it supports different patterns for generating random password:

```
KeePass::Password.generate("d{10}") # => random 10-digit string (may start with 0!)
```

A documentation for KeePass patterns can be found [here](http://keepass.info/help/base/pwgenerator.html).

Answer (score 7):

Just because it wasn't mentioned, the `Kernel#sprintf` method (or it's alias `Kernel#format` in the [Powerpack Library](https://github.com/bbatsov/powerpack)) is generally preferred over the `String#%` method, as mentioned in the [Ruby Community Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Of course this is highly debatable, but to provide insight:

The syntax of @quackingduck's answer would be

```
# considered bad
'%010d' % rand(10**10)

# considered good
sprintf('%010d', rand(10**10))
```

The nature of this preference is primarily due to the cryptic nature of `%`. It's not very semantic by itself and without any additional context it can be confused with the `%` modulo operator.

Examples from the [Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide):

```
# bad
'%d %d' % [20, 10]
# => '20 10'

# good
sprintf('%d %d', 20, 10)
# => '20 10'

# good
sprintf('%{first} %{second}', first: 20, second: 10)
# => '20 10'

format('%d %d', 20, 10)
# => '20 10'

# good
format('%{first} %{second}', first: 20, second: 10)
# => '20 10'
```

To make justice for `String#%`, I personally really like using operator-like syntaxes instead of commands, the same way you would do `your_array << 'foo'` over `your_array.push('123')`.

This just illustrates a tendency in the community, what's "best" is up to you.

More info in [this blogpost](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/06/27/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-2-favor-sprintf-format-over-string-number-percent/).

Answer (score 6):

I ended up with using Ruby kernel `srand`

`srand.to_s.last(10)`

Docs here: [Kernel#srand](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel:srand)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an expression that will use one fewer method call than quackingduck's example.

```
'%011d' % rand(1e10)
```

One caveat, `1e10` is a `Float`, and `Kernel#rand` ends up calling `to_i` on it, so for some higher values you might have some inconsistencies. To be more precise with a literal, you could also do:

```
'%011d' % rand(10_000_000_000) # Note that underscores are ignored in integer literals
```

Answer (score 4):

`('%010d' % rand(0..9999999999)).to_s`

or

`"#{'%010d' % rand(0..9999999999)}"`

Comment: this is really good solution, why isn't this not more up-voted ?

Answer (score 4):

To generate a random, 10-digit string:

```
# This generates a 10-digit string, where the
# minimum possible value is "0000000000", and the
# maximum possible value is "9999999999"
SecureRandom.random_number(10**10).to_s.rjust(10, '0')
```

---

Here's more detail of what's happening, shown by breaking the single line into multiple lines with explaining variables:

```
  # Calculate the upper bound for the random number generator
  # upper_bound = 10,000,000,000
  upper_bound = 10**10

  # n will be an integer with a minimum possible value of 0,
  # and a maximum possible value of 9,999,999,999
  n = SecureRandom.random_number(upper_bound)

  # Convert the integer n to a string
  # unpadded_str will be "0" if n == 0
  # unpadded_str will be "9999999999" if n == 9_999_999_999
  unpadded_str = n.to_s

  # Pad the string with leading zeroes if it is less than
  # 10 digits long.
  # "0" would be padded to "0000000000"
  # "123" would be padded to "0000000123"
  # "9999999999" would not be padded, and remains unchanged as "9999999999"
  padded_str = unpadded_str.rjust(10, '0')
```

Answer (score 3):

I just want to modify first answer. `rand (10**10)` may generate 9 digit random no if 0 is in first place. For ensuring 10 exact digit just modify

```
code = rand(10**10)
while code.to_s.length != 10
code = rand(11**11)
```

end

Answer (score 3):

Try using the SecureRandom ruby library.

It generates random numbers but the length is not specific.

Go through this link for more information: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Comment: e.g. `10.times.map{ SecureRandom.random_number(9)}.join`

Comment: I ended up using the following as it was about 25% faster than `10.times.map...`  `SecureRandom.random_number(10**10).to_s`

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to generate n digit random number -

```
Random.new.rand((10**(n - 1))..(10**n))
```

generate 10 digit number number -

```
Random.new.rand((10**(10 - 1))..(10**10))
```

Comment: For 10 digit number the range should be `(10**(10 - 1))...(10**10)` because the range end is a 11-digit number and which is inclusive in the range when `..` is used as the range operator.

Answer (score 2):

This technique works for any "alphabet"

```
(1..10).map{"0123456789".chars.to_a.sample}.join
=> "6383411680"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use straightforward below.

```
rand(10 ** 9...10 ** 10)
```

Just test it on IRB with below.

```
(1..1000).each { puts rand(10 ** 9...10 ** 10) }
```

Comment: Will this include last number of range object ? which is actually 11 digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
rand(9999999999).to_s.center(10, rand(9).to_s).to_i
```

is faster than

```
rand.to_s[2..11].to_i
```

You can use:

```
puts Benchmark.measure{(1..1000000).map{rand(9999999999).to_s.center(10, rand(9).to_s).to_i}}
```

and

```
puts Benchmark.measure{(1..1000000).map{rand.to_s[2..11].to_i}}
```

in Rails console to confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer, using the [`regexp-examples`](https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples) ruby gem:

```
require 'regexp-examples'

/\d{10}/.random_example # => "0826423747"
```

There's no need to "pad with zeros" with this approach, since you are immediately generating a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work even on ruby 1.8.7:

> rand(9999999999).to_s.center(10, rand(9).to_s).to_i

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is use `Array.new()` instead of `.times.map`. Rubocop recommends it.

Example:

```
string_size = 9
Array.new(string_size) do
   rand(10).to_s
end
```

Rubucop, TimesMap:

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Performance/TimesMap

Comment: it works for me! `(Array.new(string_size) { rand(10).to_s }).join`

Answer (score 0):

In my case number must be unique in my models, so I added checking block.

```
  module StringUtil
    refine String.singleton_class do
      def generate_random_digits(size:)
        proc = lambda{ rand.to_s[2...(2 + size)] }
        if block_given?
          loop do
            generated = proc.call
            break generated if yield(generated) # check generated num meets condition
          end
        else
          proc.call
        end
      end
    end
  end
  using StringUtil
  String.generate_random_digits(3) => "763"
  String.generate_random_digits(3) do |num|
    User.find_by(code: num).nil?
  end => "689"(This is unique in Users code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
x = 10  #Number of digit
(rand(10 ** x) + 10**x).to_s[0..x-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Random 10 numbers:

```
require 'string_pattern'
puts "10:N".gen
```